# Dibujar diagrama E-R a partir de unas tablas

Tags: base-de-datos, diagrama-er

Hola alguien sabría decirme cómo sería el diagrama E-R de estas tablas? Por más que lo intento no consigo desarrollar algo que me tenga sentido, creo que me está costando entender como se hace.

```
TABLA DE AUTORES
 - ID_AUTOR, PK
 - NOMBRE
 - APELLIDO

TABLA DE TITULOS
 - ID_TITULO, PK
 - TITULO
 - ID_AUTOR, FK

TABLA DE TEMAS
 - ID_TEMA, PK
 - NOMBRE
 - ID_TITULO, FK

TABLA DE LECTORES
 - ID_LECTOR, PK
 - NOMBRE
 - APELLIDO
 - DOMICILIO
 - ID_CIUDAD, FK
 - TELEFONO

TABLA DE CIUDADES
 - ID_CIUDAD_ID, PK
 - NOMBRE

TABLA DE PRESTAMOS
 - ID_PRESTAMO, PK
 - ID_LECTOR, FK
 - ID_TITUTLO, FK
 - FECHA

TABLA DE HISTORICO
 - ID_LECTOR, FK, PK
 - ID_TITULO, FK, PK
 - FECHA_PRESTAMO
 - FECHA_DEVOLUCION
```

Gracias de antemano si alguien puede ayudarme!! Sludos!

Answer (score 0):

sí como tú dices es la primera parte de un ejercicio pero no me da ningún tipo de información para realizar el diagrama ER de ahí mi duda. Directamente me indica las tablas que he mencionado y a continuación me hace estas siete preguntas. Mi intención era que si alguien me puede ayudar con el diagrama ya que no encuentro forma alguna de hacerlo y yo ya responder a las preguntas. A ver si alguien es capaz de resolverlo.
Adjunto las preguntas que hacen a continuación a ver si pueden ser útiles para algo.

1. Dibujar el diagrama E-R de las tablas descritas.
2. ¿Es correcto el diseño? Explicar.
3. ¿Qué ocurre si dos autores trabajan juntos en el mismo título?
4. ¿Debería la columna DIRECCIÓN de la tabla LECTORES tener su propia tabla? ¿Por
   qué o por qué no?
5. Cuando un lector toma prestado un libro, se hace una entrada en la tabla
   PRESTAMOS. Cuando devuelve el libro, se borra esa entrada y se hace otra en la
   tabla de HISTORICO.
6. ¿Es una buena idea? ¿Infringiré alguna regla? Si es así, ¿cuál o cuáles? ¿Debería
   tener en su lugar una sola tabla PRESTAMOS con una columna
   FECHA_DEVOLUCION? ¿Por qué sí o por qué no?
7. Dibujar el diagrama E-R con el nuevo diseño ya corregido.

[image: primera parte]

[image: segunda parte]

Comment: esto agrégalo a la pregunta original, editándola. Esta es la seccion de respuestas.

Comment: No me permite editar la original me aparece este mensaje: Existe otra edición de esta publicación que espera que se la apruebe. No se pueden enviar más ediciones hasta que se revise la edición pendiente.

Comment: Apruebala y luego edita entonces

Comment: Si eres el autor original de la pregunta, solicita [fusionar tus cuentas](/contact) en _Problema de Cuenta_ > _Necesito combinar perfiles de usuario_ (aunque a ver si lo hacen: hay huelga) :) Además, [**aquí no se hacen tareas**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320), ni se dan orientaciones ni tutorías. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Bueno no busco que se me haga ninguna tarea por eso no había colgado las 7 preguntas ya que las tenía pensado hacer yo. Lo que busco es que alguien me ayude a saber hacer ese diagrama ER ya que no tengo claro como se hace. No creo que pida nada de otro mundo como para que no se pueda comentar en un foro...